Custom DataGrid template column with ListView in ListView - ScrollViewer resize issue
I am currently developing a control that has a DataGrid as the main parent and one of the columns is a listview which has another listview inside.
I am trying to re-evaluate the scroll content when I modify dynamically the node size from the listview.
 <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FrozenColumnCount="2" ColumnHeaderHeight="30"
                 SelectionMode="Single"
                 SelectionUnit="Cell"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                 PreviewMouseWheel="DataGridControl_OnPreviewMouseWheel"
                 CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                 GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
                 CanUserDeleteRows="False">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn/> <!-- Some simple binding here -->
      <DataGridTextColumn/> <!-- Some simple binding here -->
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sequence">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                      <ListView.Template>
                           <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                              <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="ItemsScroll">
                                 <ItemsPresenter />
                              </ScrollViewer>
                           </ControlTemplate>
                        </ListView.Template>
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                              <WrapPanel/>
                           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                              <Grid Margin="2" Name="BorderText">
                                  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OPs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                          <DataTemplate>
                                             <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Margin="4" Height="40">
                                                <Border.Width>
                                                   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SizeConverter}">
                                                      <Binding Path="DataContext.NodeSize" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
                                                      <Binding Path="Seconds" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                                   </MultiBinding>
                                                </Border.Width>

                                                <Grid>
                                                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                      <RowDefinition/>
                                                      <RowDefinition/>
                                                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>

                                                   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" >
                                                      <Run Text="{Binding Seconds}"/>
                                                      <Run Text=" sec"/>
                                                   </TextBlock>
                                                </Grid>
                                             </Border>
                                          </DataTemplate>
                                       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                       <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                             <WrapPanel/>
                                          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    </ListView>
                                 </Border>
                              </Grid>
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                     </ListView>
                  </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

On PreviewMouseWheel I am resizing the node size of the second listview.
This DataGrid has two fixed columns and after that a column that its nodes can be resized on width.
If I "zoom out" then the DataGrid scrollviewer resizes properly.
When I try to "zoom in" the scrollviewer keeps the max size of the content and I need the scrollviewer to resize based on the current visibile size.
When opening the application:

When zoom out:

After that when I zoom in the size of the scrollviewer remains the same

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Try this on ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"

@MustafaMutasim Sadly, it's still the same effect. No resize of the content area
